# undefined reference to functions of quadmath lib (__float128)

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, linker-errors

I stucked with a problem when try to use any quadmath fnct. (at the beginning, I tried to use float128.hpp of boost lib. As float128.hpp is based on `__float128` and, of course, with float128.hpp I use a simple cmath lib. anyway there are the same errors with quadmath lib).

Tried to read other related questions, but the decisions did not help.
may be have missed something.

For example, here a simply test program to show:

```
extern "C" {
#include <quadmath.h>
}
int main()
{
__float128 a = 2.0q;
expq(a);
return 0;
}
```

the result of compile is:

```
||=== Build: Release in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler 7.2 (x64)) ===|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x21)||undefined reference to `expq'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

When I opened quadmath.h I saw that all functions are extern. OK. The functions must exist and the code for it is somewhere else. The linker has to be able to find it but for some reason the linker don't find where the function is defined.
I think the problem with the linker, there may be a problem in another. Anybody know how to solve it? thanks who will respond

just in case: I use code blocks v. 16.01 with minGW64 v. 7.2 (win7)

Comment: Look [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/float128_hints.html) for some hints on using boost's float128. They even include [an example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/math/example/float128_example.cpp) of some of the things that can go wrong. I encourage you to read over that example.

Comment: You also need to specify the quadmath library to the linker: `g++ -O3 -std=gnu++11 test.cpp -I/c/modular-boost/libs/math/include -I/c/modular-boost -lquadmath -o test.exe`

Comment: What is the compilation command?